# Using RelayCommand to send complex data to a MVVM model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, relaycommand

I have a complex query interface that I need to be passed on via a RelayCommand to my Model. This consists of some comboboxes, checkboxes and text inputs.

I can easily pass on a single commandparameter (i.e. RelayCommand, etc), but how would I encapsulate the commands, should it be RelayCommand,, etc. This seems a little excessive.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acceptable solution is to bind all your comboboxes, checkboxes and text inputs to particular properties of your view model and then use props values in your RelayCommand handler instead of passing data as CommandParameter.

Here is an example:

Your XAML:

```
<TextBox Text={Binding Arg1} />
<TextBox Text={Binding Arg2} />
<Button Command={Binding Cmd} />
```

Your ViewModel.cs:

```
public string Arg1 { get; set; }
public string Arg2 { get; set; }
public ICommand Cmd { get; set; }

... 

Cmd = new RelayCommand(OnCmd);

...

// We will not use command parameter at all
private void OnCmd(object o) 
{
    // Some logic that uses a lot of arguments
    Console.WriteLine(Arg1 + Arg2);
}
```

Comment: Why would this be considered a workaround, and not using the pattern as designed.

Comment: Yes, this is the typical pattern of usage in my experience.  The parameter is rarely used.

Comment: Perfect, totally great and useful answer, well done everyone.